# Exponential law and cones reference

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given a map $\omega: A\to \Omega X$, one can set up the diagram
[image]

and construct the map $\sigma : \Sigma A\to X$.
It's pretty easy to check that the homotopy classes
of $\omega$ and $\sigma$ correspond under the isomorphism
$[A, \Omega X]\cong [\Sigma A, X]$ given by the exponential law.  I'd like a good reference for this fact.

Comment: This is essentially a basic Peterson-Stein formula. See John Harper's *Secondary Cohomology Operations* chptr. 3.4 for a much more general statement (and a very careful treatement of signs!).

Comment: Ok!  I wouldn't have thought to check there, thanks!